# Excel formula to extract string from text

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm using the following formula to extract a string from text in a cell by getting rid of `-DCS`.

The text contained in the cell: `Q074-SARE_MANSONG-DCS`

Formula:`IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("DCS",H22)),LEFT(H22,FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(H22,"-DCS","@",LEN(H22)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(H22,"-",""))))-1),([@[<HELPER><SITE>]]))`

Desired reslut: `Q074-SARE_MANSONG`

The problem is that it is not working for all cells. Can someone please tell me what it is that I'm doing wrong. Thanks.

Comment: next time make sure to post some sample data especially the ones that are not returning the expected result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If "-DCS" is always at the end of the string:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-DCS","")
```

Answer (score 3):

Use one of these formulas instead (assuming your data is in A1)

`=left(A1,len(A1)-4)` or `=SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-DCS","")`